# Set date of Outlook task from cell value via Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a task in Outlook with reminder via Excel.

My code gives

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

on line

```
.StartDate = CDate(DelDate)
```

How do I set date of task from cell value?

```vb
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutTask As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ads As String
    Dim Subj As String
    Dim Body As String
    Dim DelDate As Date
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Ads = ws.Cells(4, 2).Value
    Subj = ws.Cells(7, 2).Value
    Body = ws.Cells(4, 9).Value
    DelDate = ws.Cells(10, 6).Value
    DelHour = ws.Cells(12, 6).Value
     
    Dim myRecipient As Object
    Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(Cells(4, 2))
    myRecipient.Resolve

    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        With OutTask
            .Subject = Subj
            .StartDate = CDate(DelDate)
            .DueDate = CDate(DelDate)
            .ReminderTime = CDate(DelDate)
            .Body = Body
            .Assign
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    Set OutTask = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Excel]

Comment: Change `StartDate` to `DueDate`.

Comment: @KostasK. DueDate gives the same error

Comment: You set both the start and due date, try to comment out the start date. Also check the value of `DelDate` before attempting to convert it to a date.

Comment: Start commented out, left only DueDate and still the same error. Cell with date is in format DD/MM/YYYY. I am using almost the same template to send email at certain date and it reads this value correctly.

Comment: Strange, I have working code the uses the due date. Try to supply `Date` (today's date) to see if the error occurs while converting to date.

Comment: It still gives the same error `.DueDate = Date`. (StartDate commented out)